# share via socialsharing.shareWithOptions () a base64 type imgData as a whatsapp document

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I have a problem

```
        document.getElementById("divhidden").innerHTML = html;
        var elemento = document.getElementById("divhidden");
        html2canvas(elemento, {width: 600}).then(function(canvas){
            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image");
            document.getElementById("divhidden").innerHTML = "";
            console.log(imgData);
```

This imgData is a base64 image. and the following code is used to share on whatsapp

```
var options = {
            message: null,
            files: [imgData],
            chooserTitle: null,
            appPackageName: 'com.whatsapp'
          };
          window.plugins.socialsharing.shareWithOptions(options);
```

However, the image would have to be shared as a document, so as not to lose quality.
If anyone has any ideas for me they are solving this problem.